# Add FedEx Shipping in drop down prestashop shopping cart

Tags: php, ajax, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.6, fedex

I am using FedEx shipping in prestashop and the shipping is showing in a TABLE as Radio Buttons.

I want to display this shipping as a Drop Down and that in the Shopping Cart table just below the last product in the cart list.

Please see the image below

[image: Here I want to see the FedEx Shipping as a Drop Down]

What I have done is simply included the order-carrier.tpl file to the place where I wanted it to display but this works when a page loads and as soon I change the shipping options from the list every things gets blank and distorted.

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./order-steps.tpl"}
```

I understand that this is not the right way. I need HOOK it from where . Really I don't know how to this. I am a beginner prestashop user .

Please help/ guide me.

Comment: And what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: The code written in order-carrer.tpl which is responsible for fetching the list of shipping in tabular format which I cutted and pasted to my desired section and modified it but its not working.

Comment: Maybe you should share it so people can tell you why it is not working.

Comment: Actually I have done many things but none worked.

Comment: Ok. let me share my recent changes. Give me few mins..

Comment: Added my recent work.

Answer (score 0):

There are no default hooks in that place, so you can [create new](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks) and use it in your module.
OR
check **order-carrier.tpl** in your theme folder, there default hooks, you can use this code.